# The dimension clientWidth and clientHeight are wrong on React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I have a problem with setting the dimension inside the canvas, so I'm creating a demo for my work and I'm building the base for rendering the graph with the module [ngraph](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph).

So this is the my Main component on React

```
class AppComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      open: false
    };

    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);
  }

  openDrawer(value) {
    this.setState({open: value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Drawer
          modal
          dismissible={true}
          open={this.state.open}
          className="content-drawer"
        >
          <IconButton className="drawer-icon-button-personal"
                      onClick={() => this.openDrawer(false)}>
            <MaterialIcon icon='close'/>
          </IconButton>
          <DrawerTitle tag="h2" className="drawer-title">
            Vincent Info
          </DrawerTitle>
          <DrawerContent>

          </DrawerContent>
        </Drawer>

        <DrawerAppContent className='drawer-app-content'>
          <TopAppBar className="topbar-app-personal">
            <TopAppBarRow>
              <TopAppBarSection align='start'>
                <TopAppBarIcon navIcon tabIndex={0}>
                  <MaterialIcon hasRipple icon='menu' onClick={() => this.openDrawer(true)}/>
                </TopAppBarIcon>
                <TopAppBarTitle>Vincent Builder</TopAppBarTitle>
              </TopAppBarSection>
              <TopAppBarSection align='end' role='toolbar'>
                <TopAppBarIcon actionItem tabIndex={0}>
                  <MaterialIcon
                    icon='stars'
                    onClick={() => window.open('https://vincenzopalazzo.github.io')}
                  />
                </TopAppBarIcon>
              </TopAppBarSection>
            </TopAppBarRow>
          </TopAppBar>
          <TopAppBarFixedAdjust className="container-app">
            <NGraphContainer/>
          </TopAppBarFixedAdjust>
        </DrawerAppContent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my component to render the graph `<NGraphContainer/>`, your code is:

```
class NGraphContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      graph: null,
      typeRenderer: 'pixel',
      typeGraph: 'transaction'
    };

    this.buildGraph = this.buildGraph.bind(this);
  }

  buildGraph() {
    //TODO call an method for cerate the graph
    let graph = require('ngraph.generators').grid(5, 5);
    this.renderGraph(graph);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   let container = document.querySelector('.container-ngraph');
    this.setState({
      container: container
    })
  }

  renderGraph(graph) {
   let render = RenderGraph(graph, {
      container: this.state.container
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-ngraph">
        </div>
          <Fab icon={<i className="material-icons icon-black">account_balance_wallet</i>}
               className="top-bar-personal-one icon-black"/>
          <Fab icon={<i className="material-icons icon-black">trending_up</i>}
               className="top-bar-personal-thee"
               onClick={() => this.buildGraph()}/>
          <Fab icon={<i className="material-icons icon-black">settings</i>}
               className="top-bar-personal-two"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

inside the div `<div className="container-ngraph">` I have to build the render graph with [ngraph.pixel](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.pixel) and it builds the graph inside the canvas, and it builds the canvas inside the div with the className *container-ngraph*.

The module builds the canvas with the dive dimension so with this code

```
 renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
```

The my CSS is:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto' !important;
  color: #fff;
  background: #222;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.index img {
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.drawer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drawer-app-content {
  flex: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.top-app-bar-fix-adjust {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.mdc-drawer--dismissible {
  top: auto;
}

.topbar-app-personal{
  background-color: #424242 !important;
}

.content-drawer{
  background-color: #424242 !important;
}

.drawer-title{
  text-align: center !important;
  color: aliceblue !important;
}

.drawer-icon-button-personal{
  right: 0em;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

.container-ngraph{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-bar-personal-one{
  background-color: #ffbd39;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 1rem !important;
  right: 1rem !important;
}

.top-bar-personal-thee{
  background-color: #ffbd39;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 6rem !important;
  right: 1rem !important;
}

.top-bar-personal-two{
  background-color: #ffbd39;
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 11rem !important;
  right: 1rem !important;
}

.container-ngraph{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.container-app{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

i.icon-black {
  color: black;
}

canvas{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

also, I'm using [this react component](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react)

### Problem

When building the graph the canvas component have the height=0 and I don't see the graph, I don't know the problem and I'm new with react, can you help me to fix this error and can you help me understand why this error?

The code html generated by react is:

```
<div class="container-ngraph">
<canvas width="1920" height="0" tabindex="-1" style="width: 1920px; height: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(container.clientHeight)?

Comment: @DanielDuong I get 0 value; I'm public also my css

Comment: Seems to me like your problem is that container has no height.
Maybe give .container-ngraph some height in css
Seems to me like you are doing some chicken and egg stuff. Where canvas is a child of .container-ngraph and .container-ngraph is dependant on it's children for height.

Comment: Also if canvas is relative to it's container,
you should just be able to set height and width to 100%

Comment: The my error is stupud, you have right, if I add the value `height: 100vh !important;` the error not longer exist